# Preg_match one word followed with double quotes

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

I searched all the web but did not solve my problem.

I need a regular expression to match or replace a word folowed with a double quote.

Example :

> uniquehereuniqueyouunique"can"uniquegetuniquefoounique"bar"

I need to replace all unique" by something (ex notunique). I tried :

> preg_replace("/unique\"/", 'notunique'￼, $contents);

but that don't match.

thanks for your help

Comment: Works for me. How do you use it?

Comment: This example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found it !

```
preg_replace('/unique."/', 'notunique'￼, $contents);
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the example you've given. It matches `unique` followed by any character, followed by double quote.

Comment: Then you've tried it with another string than the example given .